# EF entity is still part of parent collection after remove

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core 2.2 project with Entity Framework Core 2.2.4.

I'd like to do the following:

1. List items
2. Remove an entity (`dbset.remove`)
3. Check the parent for the number of children (now reduced by the removed one)
4. Do further, unrelated things
5. Call `.SaveChanges()` at the very end

My problem is this: in step 2, I get a count of items that does not take into account that I just removed one of it. I do not understand why, as I thought the changetracking should do the job knowing there is one of them removed (even when not saved to database).

I use `_ctx` as my database context over the whole project.

```cs
public class Transaktion
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public ICollection<TransPosition> Positionen { get; set; }
        = new List<TransPosition>();
}

public class TransPosition
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("TransaktionId")]
    public Transaktion Transaktion { get; set; }
    public int TransaktionId { get; set; }
}

Transaktion t = _ctx.Transaktionen.Find(entity.TransaktionId);
int counter = t.TransPositionen.Count();
//counter = 8

TransPosition pos = _dbSet.Find(Id);
_dbSet.Remove(pos);

Transaktion t = _ctx.Transaktionen.Find(entity.TransaktionId);
counter = t.TransPositionen.Count();
//STILL a count of 8
```

I would have expected to get a number of 7, as the `Find` should have the information of the one deleted entity.

Do I have a misunderstanding of this (obviously I do)?

Comment: You should also call SaveChanges to commit your remove.

Comment: It isn't actually removed until you do `SaveChanges`.

Comment: If you already know entities which are removed, just filter a list to get only not removed entities

Comment: Does it work when you remove the property initializer value `new List<TransPosition>();` and/or set the property to `virtual`? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Most likely a bug. Might be related to [this behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#cascade-deletions-now-happen-immediately-by-default), hence eventually fixed in 3.0

Comment: @Progman No, tried both, did not change it.

Comment: @IvanStoev It is not about deleting the parent and expect the children to be removed.

Comment: So my expectation that EF would exclude entities already marked as deleted seems to prove wrong. Then that is my problem.

I want to avoid calling `SaveChanges` before other things (mentioned at 4.) did happen (it is about calculating volume discound), as this belongs to the same transaction (database-wise).

Comment: @Dominic I understand that. And I would expect the behavior you are explaining. But my point was that both cascade delete and remove entity operations use navigation property fixup process at some point, so it's possible that currently it is invoked late (after `SaveChanges`). And fixing cascade delete apply point *might* fix this as well. Currently it is what it is, there is nothing you can do other than using `Remove` from parent collection rather than from db set.

Comment: @IvanStoev Hm, yes, that could make sense. Just were about to dig into that and it seems to correlate. I guess this explaination could give me peace on it and I'll check to get it solved otherwise meanwhile.

Comment: I'm almost sure EF6 works the way you expect. And for some unknown reason EF Core designers decided to change that. The current cascade delete behavior is just an example of similar *wrong* decision in EF Core. But it is what it is - either live with it or solve it otherwise :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you getting the count at step 2? Because until SaveChanges() has been called, nothing is committed. All the change tracker does, is track changes (i.e. it marks the entity as deleted) so that when the SaveChanges() call is made, it knows what to do with it.

Comment: Added the two lines to my code: Just using `Count()` on the `ICollection` property of the parent.

Comment: Yeah, so Count() is a terminating LINQ statement, I would expect it to call the database. Because you havent called SaveChanges() at that point, the database is unchanged. You can check that by running SQL Profiler and stepping over that line in code. The answer is to call SaveChanges() before you do your count. Try that, and you should see the result you're expecting

Comment: As I also supposed that to happen I already checked the output, but there is clearly no second call to the database for that (neither for the remove, for obvious reason, but nor for the second 'Find'.
It looks as @Ivan Stoev was right - currently this is an expected behavoir of ef-core over ef6.